# Understanding GDDR5 clamshell mode

Tags: addressing, ddr3, gpu

Let suppose a 256 bit memory controller is installed on a PCB with GDDR5 memory modules.

In **normal mode** you can split the lines into 8 group of 32 bit and drive 8 modules x 1Gbit (128 MB) = 1 GB of total frame buffer memory.

In **clamshell mode** you can split the lines into 16 group of 16 bit and drive 16 modules x 1Gbit (128 MB) = 2 GB of total frame buffer memory.

The question is: how is it possible to address 128 MB using only 16 bit?

Does it use multiplexed addresses?

What about the throughput, is it really the same on both configuration?

Comment: I've corrected several instances of "125 MB" to "128 MB" in your question. Keep in mind 1 GB of memory is 1024 MB (2^30 bytes), not 1000 MB (10^9 bytes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In normal mode you can split the lines into 8 group of 32 bit and drive 8 modules x 1Gbit (128 MB) = 1 GB of total frame buffer memory.
>
> In clamshell mode you can split the lines into 16 group of 16 bit and drive 16 modules x 1Gbit (128 MB) = 2 GB of total frame buffer memory.

"The lines" that you're referring to here are lines of the **data bus**, not the address bus. The address bus is multiplexed in GDDR5 SGRAM.

In normal mode, each memory module has its own 32-bit data bus. In clamshell mode, the memory modules are grouped into pairs; in each pair, both modules share address (and control) signals, but have separate 16-bit data busses.

[image: from Elpida "Introduction To GDDR5 SGRAM"]

Since the combined width of all data busses is the same either way (256 bits), the throughput is identical.

Comment: What does it imply having shared address signals ? Is the data stripped across every pair ?

Comment: @Bemipefe Correct. In clamshell mode, each pair of memory modules is accessed in the same pattern, but reads/writes different data.